# Paypal is not showing on my magento 1.9.2.3 store

Tags: magento, paypal, payumoney

Paypal and other custom payment methods are not visible in front end.

1. I have enabled Paypal > Properly configured. > Base Currency set to USD > Country is set to USA : But still no luck.
2. Even any custom payment gateway (Payumoney) is not visible in front end but properly installed in my theme.

I have gone through all the Paypal magento issue on Forums and everywhere but no luck. Please help if anybody can..

My site is http://thepeekaboodesigns.com/

Comment: did you configure paypal express checkout?

Comment: Yes. Configured both Paypal options either. But still not showing.

Comment: Dude, community is always for help. So why would you mind if I posted this here? After all I am looking for a solution. If you cant provide solution then please stay away.

Answer (score 0):

There can be 2 possible things going wrong. 
1. Logged in with NO Admin Rights. So there is no EDIT permissions.
2. On your left had side, it is in the store view. To make any change, it should be in default config or Main site view.